# Best ListViewAdapter for multiple row types?

Tags: android, listadapter

I need to implement a ListAdapter for multiple row types.  So pick a layout per row based on the content of that row.  I would like to hear some opinions on the merits of the different types of ListAdapters for accomplishing this.  I don't expect to have thousands of rows or even a hundred, but I may potentially have quite a few different layouts and need a flexible easy to understand implementation.

So I am considering

BaseAdapter

ArrayAdapter

CursorAdapter

SimpleCursorAdapter

What are some of the advantages/disadvantages of these adapters.  Would a cursor based adapter be better?

I want a it to be flexible, easy to change and work reliably.

Answer (score 3):

The adapters are there to adapt a data source to the view, so it really comes down to your data source.

- If its a database data source and you have largely straight-froward mappings of columns to text and image views, start with `SimpleCursorAdapter`.
- If its a database data source but a lot of custom mappings or if you end up overriding a lot of SimpleCursorAdapter's functionality anyway, take a look at `CursorAdapter`.
- If the data source is something that can viewed as an array, the look at `ArrayAdapter`.
- If its a custom data source or if there's a alot of custom logic for binding the data to the views that doesn't fit the other adapters, derive your own adapter from `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: Well what I will have is basically property values, so its not too complicated.  What if the data source is SharedPreferences and it deals with mostly hash property values?

Comment: @Androider - I suppose I would derive from BaseAdapter.  I'm not sure what you mean by "hash property values", but if you're implementing some application preferences, have you looked at the PreferenceActivty and related classes? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Comment: yes I just mean property values stored off in SharedPreferences.  Why would you use BaseAdapter?